# Does a thread will stop when its parent process stopped

Tags: android

I start a thread in Android Service,When Service stopped(the onDestroy method run) the thread is still run. I want to know if Service stop or try stop its thread when exit, if not how can I stop it.

Comment: Didn't understand, you want to stop your service when the thread stops or vice-versa?

Comment: once service will stopped thn thread wil automatically stop, no need to bother abt tis

Comment: the point of implementing a thread would be to handle it independently

Comment: @tang have a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case, no.Because normally a service is **not** a process.It runs in the same process with other components, activities etc, and your threads.

To stop the thread , you need set a flag in `onDestroy` indicating the thread should terminate ifself.
And in the thread, you should check whether the flag is set periodically.

Answer (score 0):

A thread will not terminate unless you kill him by yourself or through an exit condition.
If you kill the upper Thread the lower Thread will become a daemon.
This can be disabled by calling a `setDaemon(true);` in your constructor.

```
Service(){
    setDaemon( true );
  }
```

(Update) Or as stated by @suitianshi:

```
boolean terminated = false;

@Override
 public void run(){
   while ( ! terminated ){
      System.out.println( "Thread is running" );
   }         
 }

public void terminate(){
   terminated = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this,

https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

You can see the example code as well. An intent service is a service which runs in the background and terminates itself.